# Imagecache preset is missing in field configuration

Tags: views, 6

I have all the modules that could have to do with imagecache enabled. 
It's the user: picture field that I want to use an imagecache preset on. Normally if you want to configure that field in views, there should be a drop-down list at the very bottom of the configuration form right under the 'link to user's its profile'-checkbox.

I remember I had it there but now it's gone and I can't find out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the [ImageCache Profiles](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagecache_profiles)) module installed and enabled? Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... allows you to set user profile pictures that are consistent throughout your site and allows avatars on the user profile pages, nodes and comments to be a different size.

Comment: Yep that's the one. I was too sure it didn't have to do with a separate module for just that.